# Proving that $[a,b]$ is equinumerous to $[c,d]$, where $a<b$ and $c<d$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove this by showing a bijection function. I want to make sure my line of thinking is proper. Can I make a function that is $f(x) = \dfrac db x$ where $x$ is the element in $[a,b]$? would this function be bijective?

Comment: You're on the right lines! But you ought to be a little careful with the function you choose - $f(b) = d$ but what's $f(a)$? What would you like it to be?

Comment: I want it to be equal to C I believe since thats the smallest possible value in [c,d]? sorry new to discrete. @B. Mehta

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Does your function work in that regard?

Comment: @B.Mehta I guess not, what if I made it d-c / b-a?

Comment: That seems closer - what's the exact function you're using

Comment: a,b,c,d are all members of R (real numbers) and a < b and c < d and show [a,b] is equinumerous to [b,d]

Comment: No I mean, which bijection $f$ are you using

Comment: Im not sure what you mean the rest just says give a bijection f from [a,b] to [c,d]

Comment: Yes, I'm asking which bijection you think works

Comment: does the second one work since it accounts for c and b? as well? since the first one only accounts for d and b.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: I can definitely see that hint is true, but I am having trouble mapping it with my case.

Comment: @user5428151 Use this to find a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$. Can you reverse-engineer this into a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[c,d]$? If so, you should be able to construct a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $[c,d]$ using the functions you've seen so far.

Comment: Hmm Ok so yeah for [c,d] it becomes x-c / d - c should I be adding that to the top function? or multiplying it?

Comment: No. That is a function that maps $[c,d]$ into $[0,1]$. You want a function that maps $[0,1]$ into $[c,d]$. If you have this, you will have a function that maps $[a,b]$ into $[0,1]$, and another that maps $[0,1]$ into $[c,d]$. Both functions are bijections. You should be able to find a way to take the two functions and combine them into another one that maps $[a,b]$ into $[c,d]$.

Comment: I came up with this. (x-a) * ((d-c)/(b-a)) + c